# Pyexcel doesn't merge .xls files

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

I'm trying to merge multiple .xls files into a single workbook, where each file is inserted into a sheet, named with the .xls filename.

While surfing on web, I've seen the documentation of Pyexcel and a specific module which, as written here, could do the job easly.
Here's the code.

```
from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import glob 
merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob("Dir\*.xls"),"output.xls")
```

As expected, it doesn't work. Here's the console output.

```
File "..\Desktop\scripts\provaimport.py", line 48, in <module>


merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob("C:\Users\Tesisti\Desktop\forpythonscript\*.xls"),"output.xls")
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\cookbook.py", line 148, in merge_all_to_a_book
    merged.save_as(outfilename)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\meta.py", line 339, in save_as
    return save_book(self, file_name=filename, **keywords)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 51, in save_book
    return _save_any(a_source, book)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 55, in _save_any
    a_source.write_data(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\sources\file_output.py", line 38, in write_data
    **self._keywords)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\renderers\excel.py", line 30, in render_book_to_file
    save_data(file_name, book.to_dict(), **keywords)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 119, in save_data
    **keywords)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 141, in store_data
    writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\book.py", line 58, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_xls\xlsw.py", line 86, in close
    self.work_book.save(self._file_alike_object)
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "C:\Users\Tesisti\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 680, in get_biff_data
    self.__worksheets[self.__active_sheet].selected = True
```

Any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that glob.glob("Dir*.xls") returned an empty list of files. Hence pyexcel's plugin pyexcel-xls [fails to create an empty file](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/issues/120).

The current solution, I would recommend is to take the latest pyexcel-xls and use try-except statement around merge_all_to_a_book, catching empty file case.